# Simple seekbar in android

Tags: android

### I am trying to implement multiple seek Bars in a single Activity

**Filters.java**

```
public class Filters extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    private SeekBar PRICEbar,DISTANCEbar, RATINGbar; // declare seekbar object variable
    // declare text label objects
    private TextView PRICEtextProgress,DISTANCEtextProgress, RATINGtextProgress;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters);     
        PRICEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.PRICEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // set seekbar listener.
        // since we are using this class as the listener the class is "this"

        // make text label for progress value
        PRICEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PRICEtextViewProgressID);
        // make text label for action
        //textAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        DISTANCEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        DISTANCEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        DISTANCEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEtextViewProgressID);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        RATINGbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        RATINGbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        RATINGtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RATINGtextViewProgressID);



    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // change progress text label with current seekbar value
        PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
        // change action text label to changing
        //textAction.setText("changing");

        DISTANCEtextProgress.setText("Distance:: "+progress);

        RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);



    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //textAction.setText("starting to track touch");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
        //textAction.setText("ended tracking touch");       
    }

}
```

**filters.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PRICEtextViewProgressID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/PRICEseekBarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforDISTANCE"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DISTANCEtextViewProgressID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="DISTANCE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/DISTANCEseekBarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforRATING"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RATINGtextViewProgressID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Rating"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/RATINGseekBarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

[image]

---

- We can clearly that no matter which seekbar i change value of all
  changes at once
- How can i resolve this ?
- Also how can i make rating seek bar accept values like `( 1,2,3,4,5 )`
  instead of `(1234..100)`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your SeekBars are calling the same method on the same object (this) when their value changes.  There are two things you can do:

1. In your handler method, check to see which SeekBar triggered the call.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
       if (seekBar == PRICEbar)
           PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
       else if (seekBar == DISTANCEbar)
           DISTANCEtextProgress.setText("Distance:: "+progress);
       else if (seekBar == RATINGbar)
           RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);
   }
   ```
2. You can also just use in-line anonymous classes

   ```
   public class Filters extends Activity {  //Remove implements OnSeekBarChangeListener

   ...

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // load the layout
       setContentView(R.layout.filters);

       // make text label for progress value
       PRICEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PRICEtextViewProgressID);
       PRICEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.PRICEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
       PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener {
           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
           }
       });


       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       DISTANCEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEtextViewProgressID);
       DISTANCEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
       DISTANCEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener {
           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               DISTANCEtextProgress.setText("Distance:: "+progress);
           }
       });



       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       RATINGtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RATINGtextViewProgressID);
       RATINGbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGseekBarID); // make seekbar object
       RATINGbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener {
           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(
               SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Finally, 
You can use seekBar.setMax(int) to limit the max value of the seek bar to 5.

Comment: @ Byron Lo ...... Everything you have mentioned is perfect .... But Filter activity must *implements OnSeekBarChangeListener* to work ... I tried this solution :)

Comment: On the first option or the second option?  The second option should not require 'Filters' to implement OnSeekBarChangeListener because the 'Filters' object is not being used as the handler (unlike the first option where 'Filters' itself is being passed to the seekbars as the handler).